# List jobs on specific queue in Laravel + RabbitMQ

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, rabbitmq

I'm currently using Laravel 5.1 and RabbitMQ. My task requires that I list all the jobs in a specific queue, select at least one, and manipulate (purge/delete) it.

Is there a way to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, RabbitMQ allows you to get the first message from the queue and process it.

There is a way to get total messages count while calling declare a queue. But to me it looks suspicious